# Match all <g> and <image> tag except one containing a specific string

Tags: php, regex, xml

I have an SVG file, I want to remove all  tags and the image tag that is inside except one, the one  tag whose  href link contains "artworks". I use php, and for convenience here is the content of SVG file. Note that the SVG file will have the newline characters removed in order to make the regex more simple.

My regex so far is :

```
(<g transform="(?:.*)?"><\/image><\/g>)
```

which matches all  tags and the image tag that is inside

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1879 2053" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.2</desc>
<defs></defs>
<g transform="translate(939.5 1026.5)">
<image xlink:href="/home/printplusprod/public_html/media/pdp/images/filename1462961406.jpg" x="-939.5" y="-1026.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="1879" height="2053" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
<g transform="translate(939.51 1026.5) scale(2.59 2.59)">
<image xlink:href="/home/printplusprod/public_html/media/pdp/images/overlay1462961406.png" x="-362.22" y="-395.76" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="724.44" height="791.52" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
<rect x="-362" y="-395.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="724" height="791" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-opacity: 0; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(940.23 1027.12) scale(2.59 2.59)"/>
<g transform="translate(938.93 1025.83) scale(2.59 2.59)">
<image xlink:href="/home/printplusprod/public_html/media/pdp/images/filename1462961406.jpg" x="-362" y="-395.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="724" height="791" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice"></image>
</g>
<g transform="translate(784.5 1177.09) scale(1.5 1.5)">
<image xlink:href="/home/printplusprod/public_html/media/pdp/images/artworks/filename1453713655.jpg" x="-240" y="-179.875" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="480" height="359.75" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
<g transform="translate(938.93 1025.83)">
<image xlink:href="/home/printplusprod/public_html/media/pdp/images/overlay1462961406.png" x="-938.9347705562002" y="-1025.8251429695501" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="1877.8695411124004" height="2051.6502859391003" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Use XPath, not a regex.

Comment: XPath `//*[name()="g" and ./*[name()="image" and not(contains(@href, "artworks"))]]` should do the trick

Comment: A demo with XPath: https://3v4l.org/WrnWM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although XPath allows you to find elements better than regex in XML documents, this problem could be easily solved using DOMDocument and just iterating through all of the `<image>` nodes.

The code below uses `getElementsByTagName()` to find all of the `<image>` nodes and the inspects the href attribute and checks if it contains "artworks".  If it doesn't, then the node is removed (using `parentNode` to track back up from the image tag to the `<g>` node).

```
$xml = new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadXML($data);
$images = $xml->getElementsByTagName("image");
for ( $i = $images->length-1; $i>= 0; $i-- )   {
    $image = $images->item($i);
    if ( strpos($image->attributes->getNamedItem("href")->nodeValue, "artworks") === false )   {
        $g = $image->parentNode;
        $g->parentNode->removeChild($g);
    }
}
```

This assumes `$data` is the actual contents of the SVG, you would need to change this if it needed to load this directly from a file.

One thing which looks odd is that it actually goes through the `<image>` nodes backwards, the reason is that as you remove nodes, the order is changed, so removing earlier nodes moves subsequent nodes.  Doing this in reverse stops this problem.

With the above example,the result is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1879 2053" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.2</desc>
<defs/>


<rect x="-362" y="-395.5" rx="0" ry="0" width="724" height="791" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-opacity: 0; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(940.23 1027.12) scale(2.59 2.59)"/>

<g transform="translate(784.5 1177.09) scale(1.5 1.5)">
<image xlink:href="/home/printplusprod/public_html/media/pdp/images/artworks/filename1453713655.jpg" x="-240" y="-179.875" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="480" height="359.75" preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
</g>

</svg>
```